# My <li> items are not fading in

Tags: jquery, html

I just want to fade in list items using jQuery,
I tried this but no success!
It's not working,am i missing out something? do i need to add anything else to make it work?

```
<head>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready() {
            $('ul li').hide(); 
            $('ul li').each(function(index) {
                $(this).delay(50*index).fadeIn(200);
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <ul>
            <li>Sample 1</li>
            <li>Sample 2</li>
            <li>Sample 3</li>
            <li>Sample 4</li>
            <li>Sample 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a Syntax Error, because `jQuery(document).ready() {` is wrong ;)

It should be `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`. But everything else is OK! Have a look at the example below to see it working!

To see when errors are thrown please use the Developer Tool and its console from your browser <kbd>F12</kbd>

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul li').hide();

      $('ul li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(50 * index).fadeIn(200);
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>
html:

<div class="body">
  <ul>
    <li>Sample 1</li>
    <li>Sample 2</li>
    <li>Sample 3</li>
    <li>Sample 4</li>
    <li>Sample 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it using only css?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to do it for every n-th element hardcodet. So one code fpr the first, one for the second, ...